# Set express.static directory dynamically

Tags: node.js, express

I want to set root directory of exress.static in a way that request from a subdomain will have separate root folder.

I have a site with multiple subdomain, and the structure is a following

```
index.js
public/
-- site1
-- site2
-- site3
```

i want to set `public/site1` as static folder when request is from `site1.mydomain.com`  and `site2.mydomain.com` should not be able to get files from `public/site1` directory.

I have tried this:

```
app.use ((req, res, next) => {
  let hostName = req.headers.host;
  let options = domainMap[hostName];

  req.app.use (
    express.static (path.join (__dirname, 'public', options.publicDir))
  );

  next ();
});
```

domainMap holds the following object:

```
{
    site1:{
         publicDir:'site1',
    },
    site2:{
         publicDir:'site2',
    },
    site3:{
         publicDir:'site3',
    }
}
```

what it does now is it sets the public directory only for the first request, but is there any way to change i dynamically for every request ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate the desired middleware function dynamically and then call it manually.  You don't want to register it with `app.use()` because then it will be active for all requests.  That's why you need to call it manually.  Also, `express.static()` generates a middleware that already calls `next()` so you don't need to do that either except in cases where you don't call the generated middleware.

```
app.use ((req, res, next) => {
  let hostName = req.headers.host;
  let options = domainMap[hostName];
  // protect against missing or unexpected hostName
  if (options && options.publicDir) {
      let middleware = express.static(path.join (__dirname, 'public', options.publicDir));
      middleware(req, res, next);
  } else {
      // nothing to do here, keep routing
      next();
  }
});
```

Comment: this solves the issue, but I ended up rewriting the serve-static module of express in a way that fits my requirement. thanks for the clever solution though